# Removing hidden $ characters MAC OS X text file

Tags: macos, sed, hidden, vi

I need to remove repeating newline characters from a text file.  I can use sed to modify the file as necessary, but when it comes to matching the newline characters I'm having issues.  When I view the file using vi with ':set list' enabled I see something like the following:

```
No Active Message Discriminator.$
$
$
$
$
No Inactive Message Discriminator.$
$
```

The '$' represent the newline characters.  The same file viewed without ':set list' looks like this.

```
No Active Message Discriminator.




No Inactive Message Discriminator.
```

Any help in removing the repeating newline characters is appreciated.  I'm working in MAC OS X.  I have searched already (perhaps I missed something) but there does not seem to be an answer directly addressing the '$' characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try *"squeezing"* newlines with `tr`:

```
printf "a\n\n\nb\n"
a


b
```

and then with squeezing:

```
printf "a\n\n\nb\n" | tr -s '\n'
a
b
```

Or if you have a file:

```
tr -s '\n' < file
```